# TextBlock not wrapping inside grid column windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I've the following xaml definition. The textblock inside the stackpanel is not wrapping.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="NotesText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Hint="Add Notes" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="290" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
            <CheckBox x:Name="showRequester" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="option_show_to_requester" />
        </StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Mail To Technicain" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

    </Grid>
```

[image: Note the textblock stretching out of column]

What I should do to make it wrap ? Thanks.

Update:
[image]

Problem with the alignment when using data template for check box content.

Comment: My answer make the content wrap. and it is better than just make textBlock wrap. I change the ContentTemplate of CheckBox. Please read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by Providing `Width` of `TextBlock`.

Comment: It is working but I don't want give the actual size since it might create problems with different screen sizes. Is there any other way I can use ?

Comment: You can give a general width for all. or you can have grid in stackpanel

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `put a checkBox and a TextBlock into a StackPanel`. To make the CheckBox's content **Wrap**, just use **ContentTemplate** of CheckBox.

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="NotesText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Hint="Add Notes" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="290" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <!--Use ContentTemplate of CheckBox-->
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="option_show_to_requester" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
        </CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Mail To Technicain" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

    </Grid>
```

for a simple example:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Tapped="ContentRoot_Tapped">             
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0">
        <CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="wrap123123123123wrap" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>     
            </DataTemplate>
        </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="nowrap" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
    </CheckBox>            
</Grid>
```

And the run image is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks it is working. But the content and the checkbox are not aligned properly. Is there a way I can solve it ?

Comment: You can set TextAlignment of TextBlock in the DataTemplate of CheckBox.

Comment: Please check the updated image for the alignment issue.