# How to wrap text/content in checkBox wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi how do i wrap text inside the checkBox,my code:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="NDAFormWebBrowser" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,0" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="448" Width="446" 
                          Background="#FF641E7B"/>
        <CheckBox  x:Name="NDA_chkBox" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="8,464,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="75">
            <TextBlock x:Name="friendlyNameDisplay" 
                       FontSize="10" Text="{Binding FriendlyDisplayName}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="390"/>
        </CheckBox>
```

I want that the texblock should get the FriendlyDisplayName wrapped text....which i am not able to get
through my code
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The text will get wrapped when you use the TextWrapping property and setting its value as "Wrap". For the code above the text will keep on coming down as you have not fixed the height property for the textblock.

P.S.

1) Adjust the FontSize property to get better wrapping.

2) Use TextAlignment property as Center to make it neat.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including the `TextBlock` wrapping within a `DataTemplate`?

```
<CheckBox  x:Name="NDA_chkBox" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="8,464,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Height="75">
<CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="option_show_to_requester" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
    </CheckBox>
```

Have a look at this one too:

[TextBlock not wrapping inside grid column windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264533/)